# How can I change border color for TextView in RecyclerView for N seconds only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a model that is simple:
    String name;
    String score;
in the background of my application data is changed in real time for field score. 
I have simple activity with recyclerview of cardView that shows name and score.

I need to make textView score to change it's border for N seconds when score has changed. I know how to update my list when data has changed, but how to change border of textView score only for a limited time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create an AsyncTask. In the preparation phase I'd finalization phases I'd change the thickness of the view, while in the background phase I'd count the N seconds.

Comment: I have MVP architecture, I change my data in model and I am sending notifyDataSetChanged(). I am not sure where to start AsyncTask that can reach UI stuff?

Comment: You could start the AsyncTask when the score changes, so at the end of the whole process, as a decorative event.